# Preserve Order when reading ZipStream

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, zipstream

I am exposing rest Service which outputs octect-stream .
we are creating zip file using ZipOutputStream and sending it to response.

The caller needs a specific file to be read first when reading stream. is there any guaranteed way that when added file first using zipStream, the same file would be read first by caller/reader.

```
ZipEntry abc = new ZipEntry("abc.txt");
    zout.putNextEntry(abc);
```

I tried poc above, I see its working , but i dont see any doc explaining above behaviour.

Can some one please help here ?

Comment: It’s a stream. It’s sequential by its nature. Consider the meaning of ‘next’.